# mysql duplicate insert stopping

Tags: mysql

I know this question has been answered tons of time but i really want to know how this behaves properly, i went with the docs but something is still missing...

i have a table with ID but i am not using ID for inserting, nor i have any index or unique keys and not i have any plan for this: if i had to fix this,

my writing of the following :

```
insert into mytable(name,details,industry,attachments) values('abc','xyz',1,'BlobImage') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [what should be here]
```

i do not know the PK of the item being inserted so will it judge automatically or how?

Comment: If you want to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` you should have a primary key column.  What is your reason for not having one?

Comment: As far as MySQL is concerned rows with identical columns cannot be duplicates unless you create a unique index on them. You need to grab the full package or not use it at all.

Comment: if PK is mandatory then i have to use it, **but how?** @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen PKs are a good idea from DB design perspective but they aren't necessary for this specific feature to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there's some confusion about how [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) works so I'll do my best to explain it.

MySQL doesn't have any problem with duplicates:

```
mysql> create table foo (
    ->     name varchar(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (name) values ('Jim'), ('Jim'), ('Jim'), ('Jim');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| Jim  |
| Jim  |
| Jim  |
| Jim  |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Being able to avoid duplicate data at database server level is an optional feature you need to opt-in. The above example also illustrates that MySQL does not *need* primary keys at all (or keys for what it matters). All these are tools provided by the system that you can use to accomplish stuff: help have a normalised design, improve performance, etc.

Intuition can suggest that having the same data again and again can't just be right. Well, it just depends on what your data means. For instance, this is very likely to be wrong:

```
mysql> create table user (
    ->     user_id int(10) auto_increment,
    ->     username varchar(20),
    ->     password varchar(255),
    ->     primary key (user_id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user (username, password) values ('jim', '$2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user (username, password) values ('jim', '$2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user order by user_id;
+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | username | password                                                     |
+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | jim      | $2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K |
|       2 | jim      | $2y$12$QjSH496pcT5CEbzjD/vtVeH03tfHKFy36d4J0Ltp3lRtee9HDxY3K |
+---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

… but this is just fine (yet it's essentially the same design):

```
mysql> create table sign_in_log (
    ->     user_id int(10) auto_increment,
    ->     username varchar(20),
    ->     sign_in_time datetime,
    ->     primary key (user_id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into sign_in_log (username, sign_in_time) values ('jim', now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into sign_in_log (username, sign_in_time) values ('jim', now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from sign_in_log order by user_id;
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id | username | sign_in_time        |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
|       1 | jim      | 2018-07-03 09:32:22 |
|       2 | jim      | 2018-07-03 09:32:22 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a tool to further process duplicate insertions and key points are:

- You need a duplicate in the first place.
- MySQL cannot make the design decisions for you.

So first you need a situation where a given query actually fails due to having unwanted duplicate values and, for that, you need some kind of constraint that effectively triggers an error:

```
mysql> create table user_tag (
    ->     username varchar(20),
    ->     tag varchar(20),
    ->     tag_count int(10) default 1,
    ->     unique index unique_user_tag_combination (username, tag)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into user_tag (username, tag) values ('jim', 'sql');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user_tag (username, tag) values ('jim', 'sql');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'jim-sql' for key 'unique_user_tag_combination'
```

… and then you can use the tool to handle that situation and accomplish something different that a query failure, e.g.:

```
mysql> insert into user_tag (username, tag) values ('jim', 'sql') on duplicate key update tag_count = tag_count + 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into user_tag (username, tag) values ('jim', 'sql') on duplicate key update tag_count = tag_count + 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user_tag;
+----------+------+-----------+
| username | tag  | tag_count |
+----------+------+-----------+
| jim      | sql  |         3 |
+----------+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

I hope this explains why your request does not really make sense:

> nor i have any index or unique keys and not i have any plan for this

You've designed a table in such a way that it can store several rows with the same values but you want MySQL to prevent you from doing it. Those are contradictory requirements.